# What is the best practice for saving user details and resources when user deletes account?

Tags: java, php, mysql, asp.net, node.js

First sorry for the confusing tags on the post but I wanted to attract developers from multiple backend environments to join the discussion.
So the question might sound confusing but let me make it more clear.
Let's imagine you have a running SaaS application which holds sensitive data such as client's transactions, invoices, maybe some contracts which data should be always available and associated with the one exact client pretty much the data that needs to be there in case someone needs it either its the police, judge, government w/e you get the point.
I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994957/delete-user-best-practice) but it doesn't quite address my problem, basically the solution there is to have something like this in your user class(example is in PHP but it applies to every language pretty much)

```
private $deleted = false;
get, set
```

but there is one problem with this approach if the user/client changes his mind and would register again with the same email and username he would get **user already exists** error which might confuse him since he deleted his account after all.
My idea is to besides keeping the flag **deleted** I'd create naming strategy which prefixes the username with the word **deleted** which would unlock the username for the user but I guess there comes another problem with "duplicating" the username and email.
What is your approach when it comes to keeping the user's evidence in the system? Let's figure it out once and for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefix/postfixing is the right idea, but unfortunately it's not good enough in real world use cases, because what happens if the user creates an account, deletes it, creates an account with the same username again, and then deletes it again? Now you have a duplicate unique FK problem.

The better approach is to postfix the username or email address (whichever is the unique key) with a nano-second resolution timestamp. For example, let's say the PK in the database is the user's email `user@example.com`. Now they decide to delete their account, you simply update the email to `"user@example.com-" . hrtime(true)`, which now gives you a nano-second resolution timestamp appended to the PK. This makes it possible to still lookup the old account while leaving it possible to recreate a new account with the same email address.

The reason I'd prefer postfixing to prefixing is that postfix approach makes it possible to do a wildcard search on the email address with no possibility of false positives, whereas prefixing makes that search slightly more nuanced. So `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email LIKE 'user@example.com%'` yields all records for that user (deleted or otherwise).

You could of course append the string `.deleted-` followed by the timestamp to make it harder to accidentally pull up deleted emails (*assuming the TLD .deleted is never created at some point*).

> Having a flag for deleted accounts is also a good idea, but with the aforementioned scheme is typically not necessary as the user normally won't be able to guess the timestamp to be able to login to the deleted account (and more importantly the email validation mechanism should prevent this from passing as a valid email anyway).

More realistically, however, soft deletes are eventually moved out of production databases and into long-term archive storage in most real world scenarios. I've worked for several companies that do soft deletes and typically this scenario is only a temporary fix (usually to make it possible to restore old accounts within a given window or grace period), but normally the long term solution is to eventually move those records into a separate database. It's typically not that useful to keep soft deleted data in production and almost never serves any real use case for the programmer.